# Disable that acceess key sets focus to button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have created a access key Angular directive.

```
angular.module('tcne.common').directive("accessKey", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var $element = $(element);
            $element.attr("accesskey", attrs.accessKey);
            var content = $element.html();
            for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
                var char = content[i];
                if (char.toLowerCase() === attrs.accessKey.toLowerCase()) {
                    content = content.substr(0, i) + "<u>" + char + "</u>" + content.substr(i + 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            $element.html(content);
        },
        replace: false
    };
});
```

It underscores the access key in the button Label and adds the access key attribute to the element. Can I somehow prevent the accesskey from setting the button in focus? It kills the purpose of keyboard short cuts

edit: Rolled my own acccess key

```
angular.module('tcne.common').directive('accessKey', ['$compile', '$interval', function ($compile, $interval) {
    var modifierPressed = false;
    $("body").keyup(function (e) {
        if (modifierPressed && !e.altKey) {
            modifierPressed = false;
            digestScopes();
        }
    });

    $("body").keydown(function (e) {
        modifierPressed = e.altKey;
        if (modifierPressed && scopes.hasOwnProperty(String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase())) {
            var scope = scopes[String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase()];
            scope.handle();
            return;
        }

        if (modifierPressed) {
            e.preventDefault();
            digestScopes();
        }
    });

    function digestScopes() {
        for (var index in scopes) {
            if (scopes.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
                var scope = scopes[index]
                scope.$digest();
            }
        }
    }

    function isModifierPressed() {
        return modifierPressed;
    }

    var scopes = {};

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var key = attrs.accessKey.toLowerCase();

            var content = element.html();
            var char;
            for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
                char = content[i];
                if (char.toLowerCase() === key) {
                    content = content.substr(0, i) + '<u><strong ng-if="highlight()">{{char}}</strong><span ng-if="!highlight()">{{char}}</span></u>' + content.substr(i + 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            element.html(content);

            var underscoreScope = scope.$new();
            underscoreScope.char = char;
            underscoreScope.highlight = isModifierPressed;
            underscoreScope.handle = element.click.bind(element);
            scopes[key] = underscoreScope;
            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                delete scopes[key];
            });


            $compile(element.find("u"))(underscoreScope);
        },
        replace: false
    };
}]);
```

It also highlights the access key button when alt key is pressed which is nice
Any pit falls with this code? Thanks

**Found a pitfall**, `element.html` and then `$compile` will break any directives inside the element that is already compiled. So I changed to

```
var captionElement = element.contents().first(":text");
var content = captionElement.text();
```

And then I add my custom content like

```
var view = $("<span>").html(content);
captionElement.replaceWith(view);
$compile(view)(vm);
```

Please let me know if this is considered bad practice

Comment: Sorry i can't help your question however if you have jQuery included before angular `element` will be a full jQuery object, no need to wrap it. Just FYI.

Comment: I'm not familiar with angularjs, but might you be looking for JS method `blur()` ?

Comment: I'm rolling my own access key now, is there a way in Angular to get a callback when the element connected to the directive is removed from dom?

Comment: scope.$on('$destroy', ...)